# C# Xamarin Android string += does not work

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

So I've been using this piece of code in a non-xamarin project for a month now and it worked fine, transfer it over to the xamarin project and now it refuses to work. From troubleshoting I can tell its the " menu = menu + text[num] + " "; " that does not work (it does not add the strings as I want it to, it just leaves the string as "oder ", like it was set as)Also if I do "num - 1" to get the string form the array it works :/ . Is this a xamarin bug or is my code bad?

```
 public string menuEncrypt(string[] input, MainActivity ac)
    {
        //Stream Reader to String[]
        StreamReader mc = new StreamReader(ac.Assets.Open("Menu_Code.txt"));
        StreamReader mt = new StreamReader(ac.Assets.Open("Menu_Text.txt"));

        string[] code = streamToArry(mc);
        string[] text = streamToArry(mt);


        //string[] code = File.ReadAllLines(@"JittersApp/Droid/Assets/Menu Code.txt");
        //string[] text = File.ReadAllLines(@"JittersApp/Droid/Assets/Menu Text.txt");
        int codemax = code.Length;
        int current = 0;
        int im = input.Length;
        string menu = "oder ";

        while (true)
        {
            if (current < codemax)
            {
                if (current < im)
                {
                    if (text.Contains(input[current]))
                    {
                        int num = 0;
                        while (true)
                        {
                            string item = input[current];
                            if (text[num].Equals(item))
                            {
                                menu = menu + text[num] + " ";
                                break;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                num++;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    current++;
                }
                else
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                break;
            }
        }

        new AlertDialog.Builder(ac)
        .SetMessage(menu)
        .Show();
        return menu;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I got around this by adding a useless line to both the text files and then added + 1 to the variable `num`, here's the code :)

```
 public string menuEncrypt(string[] input, MainActivity ac)
    {
        //Stream Reader to String[]
        StreamReader mc = new StreamReader(ac.Assets.Open("Menu_Code.txt"));
        StreamReader mt = new StreamReader(ac.Assets.Open("Menu_Text.txt"));

        string[] code = streamToArry(mc);
        string[] text = streamToArry(mt);


        //string[] code = File.ReadAllLines(@"JittersApp/Droid/Assets/Menu Code.txt");
        //string[] text = File.ReadAllLines(@"JittersApp/Droid/Assets/Menu Text.txt");
        int codemax = code.Length;
        int current = 0;
        int im = input.Length;
        string menu = "oder ";

        while (true)
        {
            if (current < codemax)
            {
                if (current < im)
                {
                    if (text.Contains(input[current]))
                    {
                        int num = 0;
                        while (true)
                        {
                            string item = input[current];
                            if (text[num + 1].Equals(item))
                            {
                                menu = menu + code[num + 1] + " ";
                                break;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                num++;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    current++;
                }
                else
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                break;
            }
        }

        new AlertDialog.Builder(ac)
        .SetMessage(menu)
        .Show();
        return menu;
    }
```